# How to show the amout of numbers in a playlist in the details view in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, tags, playlists, winamp

Here's my problem. In mp3 files and other audio formats, when metadata is inserted, and you open Windows Explorer and set the view to Details, you can see the information for each track. I'm using Windows 10.

Now I was wondering if the same thing is possible for playlists, like .m3u files?
Is it possible to set some sort of custom column in Explorer, e.g. "Total Tracks" and that it shows the total amount of songs in the playlist?

[image]

Can it be done? With a setting in Windows Registry? Or do I need to install some sort of add-on?
If not, if I choose to use some other explorer like FreeCommander, is there a possibility to get it to work here?

I used to put all my playlists in Winamp, Media Library. Here I can see how many tracks are in a playlist. But the problem I find with this method is, that the playlist filenames in Winamp do not correspond with the real filenames found on my drive, which annoys me. Also, when using this method I'm stuck to Winamp, which I rather don't want to do.

Can anyone help me out? :)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

.m3u files are plain text and the Details tab of an m3u file reveals only the basic filesystem properties, so a column htat displayed with the files would requre serious coding to create a [Column Handler](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/lwef/column-handlers).

But, if you could use *shortcuts* (`.lnk` files) to your playlists, the `Track Count` could be added as the shortcut's `Comment` property -- and that *can* be displayed as a column in **Explorer**`:

[image]

Don't know if you're comfortable with code, but shortcuts for existing `.m3u` files could be creaeted with a bit of **PowerShell**

```
$M3USourcePath     = 'c:\Music'
$M3uShortcutFolder = 'c:\PlaylistShortcuts'

$wshShell = New-Object -Com wscript.shell
gci $M3USourcePath *.m3u -s | %{                                   ### -s makes search recursive
    $olnk             = $wshShell.CreateShortcut("$M3uShortcutFolder\$($_.BaseName).lnk")
    $olnk.TargetPath  = $_.FullName
    $olnk.Description = 'Track Count: {0}' -f ( (gc $_.FullName) -match '^#EXTINF' ).Count
    $olnk.Save()
}
```

and similar code could be used to create a context menu command for  the `.m3u` type  that would create a corresponding shortcut for the selected file --- that could be used as your create new playlists.

Comment: Okay, I will try it out. Not sure if shortcuts will be the thing I'm looking for. Still, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Another scripting work-around might be to calculate the track count and then rename the file so the count is included in the filename. I know both these options pale in comparison to the usefullness of a functioning file property, but I don't you're going to find that.